how to fetch the details of selected rows from a lightning data table when we have multiple lightning data tables availabe in lwc
I have 2 lightning data tables in my LWC. Under those tables, I have 2 buttons respectively. With one click of a button, I want to fetch the selected rows of the targeted lightning data table. I was trying to use
this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows()
but it fetches the reference of the first lightning datatable only not the other one. I tried to associate ID and Name as well to each of the data tables and then tried to fetch the selected rows using the following piece of code :
markup :
{openingBracket}lightning-datatable data={recordsToDisplay} columns={columns} onrowaction={getSelectedIncidentId} default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection} sorted-direction={sortDirection} sorted-by={sortedBy} onsort={onHandleSort} id="linkedJira">

{openingBracket}/lightning-datatable>

JS controller :
var lightningTableRef = this.template.querySelector('[id="lightningDataTable2"]');
var selectedRecords =  lightningTableRef.getSelectedRows();

but I am always getting null in the selectedRecords variable. Could anybody help how to fetch the selected rows from the targeted table with a click of a button?
Thanks!

You can use the newish lwc:ref for that I think:
e.g.
    <lightning-button label="Get Rows for Table 1" onclick={getrows1}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button label="Get Rows for Table 2" onclick={getrows2}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-datatable
            lwc:ref="myTable1"
            key-field="id"
            data={data1}
            columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>

    <lightning-datatable
            lwc:ref="myTable2"
            key-field="id"
            data={data2}
            columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>

//Controller
 getrows1() {
            console.log("getSelectedRows => ", JSON.stringify(this.refs.myTable1.getSelectedRows()));
    }

    getrows2() {
        console.log("getSelectedRows => ", JSON.stringify(this.refs.myTable2.getSelectedRows()));
    }

